# httr package in R - Not Getting all the observations from KOBO Data

Tags: r, get, httr, kobo

I am using following code to GET data using API from the KOBO server, it downloads only 30000 observations instead of all 85,000 observations.

```
rawdata<-GET(url,authenticate(u,pw, type = "basic"),progress())
observer <- content(rawdata,"raw",encoding="UTF-8")
observer <- read_csv(observer)
observer <- as.data.frame(observer)
```

Using same code, I am able to download all observations when smaller no of observations.

Looking for help

Comment: Does the API have a max number of rows returned per request? Are there options for getting paged results? Can you provide documentation for the API you are trying to access. It's unlikely that `httr` is limited the results in any way. It's far more likely the server it capping your results.

Comment: Don't know if API has limitations. I am using KOBO Humanitarian response server APIs, and I managed getting more than 100,000 observations in past using same APIs. Also sequence/order of the downloaded data is not maintained.